# Order Assets by date field

Tags: assets, date, ordering

I have a page which lists assets by source. I've added a date field to the asset.

How can I order the assets by this field so that the most recent is first?

[image: asset date field]

Here is my markup:

```
{% set assets = craft.assets.find({sourceId: 2}) %}

{% for asset in assets %}
    <a href="{{ asset.url }}">{{ asset.date | date('M Y') }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

Looking at the [cheat sheet for Assets](http://straightupcraft.com/cheat-sheets) it seems that these are my only options for order:      `title`, `id`, `sourceId`, `folderId`, `filename`, `kind`, `width`, `height`, `size desc`'.

Ideally I could do something like this:

```
{% set assets = craft.assets.find({sourceId: 2, order: '{{ asset.date }}'}) %}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're so close it's maddening—you should be able to order by a custom field as well:

```
{% set assets = craft.assets.find({sourceId: 2, order: 'date desc'}) %}
```

Where `date` is the name of your custom field.

From the [Craft docs](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/craft.assets#order) (emphasis added):

> Possible values include 'title', 'id', 'sourceId', 'folderId', 'filename', 'kind', 'width', 'height', 'size', 'dateCreated', and 'dateUpdated', **as well as any textual custom field handles**.

Comment: Thank you. I was so close. It works perfectly. I've also noted your edits on my post for future questions.

Comment: @NiallThompson Your question was excellent and thorough, I just did some tidying. I hope you don't mind :)